# Is $aX+bY$ $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Is $aX+bY$ $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable? If so, can someone show it rigorously? What is the relation between $\sigma(aX+bY)$ and $\sigma(X,Y)$?

Comment: If $X$ is measurable then so is $aX$, so take $a=b=1$ to simplify. Now use a standard argument involving rationals  to show that if $X,Y$ are measurable then so is $X+Y$.

Comment: To the second question: If $a$ and $b$ are fixed, $\sigma(aX+bY)\subset \sigma(X,Y)$. One can see that there is no equality on the simple example: $aX=-bY$, and $X$ is not a constant. Then $\sigma(aX+bY)$ is the trivial sigma-algebra, whereas $\sigma(X,Y)$ is non-trivial.

Comment: In fact, $\sigma(f(X,Y))\subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$ for any measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.